# parsing rss - undefined offset 0

Tags: php, regex, parsing, rss

I have a rss parsing code, but I got error message about undefined offset 0 at row 38 (`$$row = $preg_match [1] [0];` )

Here is the full parsing code:

```
<?php


echo ' <style>
.scores {font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;line-height:140%; }
.scores th {background:#6D8D9F; text-align:left; border:0; color:#fff;padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;}
.scores td {padding:2px 5px 2px 5px; margin:0; border:0;}
.scores td.dark {background:#D1DADF; }
.scores td.bright {background:#E0E8EF; }
.scores a {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none;}
.scores a:hover {color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
.scores .foot {text-align:center;background:#6D8D9F; color:#ff0000}
.scores .foot small { color:#222}
.scores small {color:#777;}
</style>'."\r\n";



$rss_file = '';
$fp = fsockopen ('www.soccerstats247.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if ($fp) {
    fputs ($fp, "GET /CompetitionFeed.aspx?langId=1&leagueId=1204 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.soccerstats247.com\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp))  {
        $rss_file .= fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
} else  {echo('RSS Error :(');}
$rss_rows = array ( "title", "link", "description", "pubDate" );
$rss_array = explode ( "<item>", $rss_file );
echo '<table class="scores"><tr><th> ';
$lineC = 0;
foreach ( $rss_array as $string ) {
    $arrData =array();
    foreach ( $rss_rows as $row ) {
        preg_match_all ( "|<$row>(.*)</$row>|", $string, $preg_match );


        $$row = $preg_match [1] [0];
        $arrData[$row] = $$row;
            }
    $tickerClass = round($lineC/2) == $lineC/2 ? 'dark' : 'bright';
    if (stripos($arrData['description'], 'SoccerStats247'  ) !== false) {
           } else {

               $result = str_replace(array('&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a rel="nofollow" href=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt;'), array(''), $arrData['description']);
    $date = date("Y.m.d", strtotime($arrData['pubDate']));

        echo '<tr><td class="'.$tickerClass.'">'.$date.' '.$result .'<br></td></tr>';
    }
    $lineC++;
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

My question: Why got I error message? What is wrong in my code? Many thanks.

Comment: check if key exists before calling it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code for you. If you var_dump the $preg_match within the loop you will see that the first 3 arrays contain information after the feed or the website itself. The 4th loop just outputs an empty array:

```
array(2) {
[0] => array(0) { }
[1] => array(0) { }
}
```

Following that are the actual arrays you want to know of the teams and game data. So yeah. basically the warning says that there isnt an actual entry in the array that you're looking for there.

Best thing to do is to

```
    if(!empty($preg_match[1]))
    {
            $$row = $preg_match [1] [0];
            $arrData[$row] = $$row;
    }
```

before you're trying to output or mainpulate the data.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now I got error message about  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in row 53

Comment: I added the if clause before I output the data. Here is the end of my current code: `$tickerClass = round($lineC/2) == $lineC/2 ? 'dark' : 'bright';
    if (stripos($arrData['description'], 'SoccerStats247'  ) !== false) {
           } else {
      $result = str_replace(array('&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a rel="nofollow" href=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt;'), array(''), $arrData['description']);
 $date = date("Y.m.d", strtotime($arrData['pubDate']));
      
      if(array_key_exists($preg_match[1][0]))
    {
      
        echo '<tr><td class="'.$tickerClass.'">'.$date.' '.$result .'<br></td></tr>';
       }
      }`

Comment: Ahhh, I do apologise. I misread you! I have altered my answer above. Instead of checking if a specific array_key_exists, try checking whether the array is empty. As shown in my example.